# Python program to read function inputs

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi guy’s I’m trying to write a python program here and I’m just learning at the moment. what I’m trying to do is get the user to enter a 6 digit number and if they enter a number which is not 6 digits I want an error message to come us stating they must enter a 6 digit number. I have a function called `def example_check_message(m):` where I have stated that the number must be 6 digits and I have a function called `def example_get_number():` when the user enters the number the get number function should call the `def example_check_message(m)` function to check the number being entered is correct but nothing is happening. I know I’m close to it but just can’t see where I’m going wrong.

```
def example_check_message(m):

    b = False,
    try:
        if m == int >= '100000' and '<1000000':
            b = True
    except:
        print 'You must enter a number'

    return b


def example_get_number():
    example_check_message(1)
    b = False

        while b == False:
            num = raw_input('Please enter a 6 digit number:')

            if example_check_message(num) == True:
                b = True
                continue
            value = int(num)
            return value


if __name__ == '__main__':
     example_check_message(1)
     example_get_number()
```

Comment: what is that supposed to do "m == int >= '100000' and '<1000000':" ? There are at least 3 different types of errors in this part of code. you probably meant `1e6 <= int(m) < 1e7`

Comment: the indentation of the `while b == False` block will surely produce an error.

Comment: That `while` loop will never iterate more than once, making it pointless.

Comment: looks like i'm miles off, i thought i was much closer than this. I'm only learning at the moment and finding it hard to find a good tutorial on it. Thanks guys for you're help think it might be easier just to forget trying to learn it at the moment.

Comment: Thanks i appreciate you're feed back

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
def example_check_message(m):
    try:
        m = int(m)
        if m >= 100000 and m < 1000000:
            return m  # <- return something useful!
    except:
        print 'You must enter a number'
    return False
```

but there are errors in this - ill give you some hint where.  this shouldn't work as-is, you'll still need to do some work and learning.

```
def example_get_number():
    example_check_message(1)
    b = False

    while b == False:  # not b is the right way here
        num = raw_input('Please enter a 6 digit number:')

        if example_check_message(num) == True:  # This could be simpler
            b = True
            continue # <- no need to continue here, just return
        value = int(num)  # <- do this already on the input!
        return value
```

Comment: Thanks for you're help, i thought i was a lot closer than i am. i'm just learning but it is looking like a nightmare and i'm finding it hard to find good tutorials on it.

Comment: i would suggest you don't need tutorials - you need some persistence. line by line, think about what each thing does.  if you are still learning, it will be a while before you can write a function the same way you can write a natural language paragraph.

Comment: Thanks i appreciate you're feed back.